# Stackdriver Metrics through Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I was curious if Stackdriver metrics are only available via the API or is there a way to send them through Pub/Sub? I'm currently not seeing any of the metrics listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-compute) for Compute Engine in my Pub/Sub output.

I did create a sink for all gce vm instances to export from Stackdriver logging in Pub/Sub and I'm not seeing any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different types of signals that Stackdriver organizes--metrics, logs, traces, errors, plus derived signals like incidents or error groups.  Logs can be [exported](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) via Pub/Sub using sinks.  Metrics, traces, and errors can only be pulled via the API today.